# Sending Variables with a Segue

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7

I am working on a simple iOS Swift app. The app has 2 view controllers and a button that has been programmed to segue to the other view controller like so:

```
@IBAction func pushMe(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("changeIt", sender: nil)
}
```

The above works but I want to be able to save 2 variables from the current view controller and make them available to the view controller I am segueing to. So I did this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "changeIt" {
        var testVar1 = "Hello"
        var testVar2 = "World"
    }
}
```

In the view controller that I am segueing to I added:

```
var testVar1:String!
var testVar2:String!
```

The app works but as soon as I try to access testVar1 or testVar2, the app crashes. I am not sure why this isn't working as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because variables were not initialized, you omitted destination view controller. Use the code below

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "changeIt" {
        let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! YourDestinationViewController
        dvc.testVar1 = "Hello"
        dvc.testVar2 = "World"
    }
}
```

Comment: I get it now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
if segue.identifier == "changeIt" {
    var testVar1 = "Hello"
    var testVar2 = "World"
}
```

All you are doing here is making new, completely separate local variables called `testVar1` and `testVar2`. They are not, by some miraculous wishful thinking, the same as the instance properties `testVar1` and `testVar2` belonging to the view controller you are segueing to. How can they be? That code never even mentions that view controller at all! If you want to set a property of a view controller, you need to talk *to that view controller*.

Think of it this way. Suppose the Dog class has a `name` property and you want to set a Dog instance's `name`. Do you do it by saying this?

```
let d = Dog()
let name = "Fido"
```

No! That creates a `name`, but it isn't the *dog's* name. You need to say this:

```
let d = Dog()
d.name = "Fido"
```

So in your code, you need to use the segue to get a reference *to the destination view controller* and set *its* properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it creating the variables on destination ViewController

```
class OtherViewController : UIViewController {
    var testVar1 : String = ""
    var testVar2 : String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var message = "\(self.testVar1) \(self.testVar2)"
        print(message)
    }
}
```

The UIStoryboardSegue has a **destinationViewController** property. It's an instance to the end point view controller you want to reach. Then now you can do this:

```
class SourceViewController : UIViewController {

    //...

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        //Some code before

        var destination = segue.destinationViewController as! OtherViewController
        destination.testVar1 = "Hello"
        destination.testVar2 = "World"

        //Some code after

    }
}
```